# Reference Zeppelin to Spark Master (in Docker Container)

Tags: apache-spark, docker, connection, docker-compose

thanks for sharing your time.

I have a Docker Set-Up of the following: 
A Docker-Compose File which starts up an Instance of Zookeeper, Solrcloud, Spark Master/Worker and Zeppelin. All of them start up perfectly and run. Solrcloud and Spark connect with Zookeeper.
Now I wanted to connect Zeppelin to the Spark Master.
But it doesnt work out for me.

In my docker-compose file I set *`ZEPPELIN_SPARK_MASTER: spark://spark:7077`* and set `SPARK_HOME`. However it doesnt work as I can see in the Spark UI (only the Spark Worker is shown). All ports are open. I deactivated the firewall and still not workin. - Ubuntu 16.04 LTS